# Does Blazor's Fluxor Library Handle Dispatched Actions Asynchronously

Tags: blazor, fluxor

I'm using the [Fluxor](https://github.com/mrpmorris/Fluxor/tree/master) library for Blazor and trying to learn about how it handles dispatched actions. I can't tell what happens when I call `Dispatcher.Dispatch(action)` but it's important to my project to know how these dispatched actions are handled. I know that the actual dispatching is based on however I call it, I'm specifically talking about what happens in the Fluxor framework.

I tried looking through the source code, but was unable to find conclusive evidence either way, as I couldn't figure out how it all worked. However, in my code I put a 10 second delay in a reducer method using `Thread.Sleep`, and it froze the program until it was finished, so I believe that suggests the state is handled synchronously, but I wanted to see if anyone else could offer some insight.

Answer (score 2):

Reducers as called synchronously.

Effects are then executed asynchronously and not awaited.